# list as value in a dictionary - cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a pokemon "database" of sorts. I want the program to output every pokemons: name, type, evolves from, evolves to. Each name is a key in my `pokemon` dictionary. Each value is another dictionary containing the information as keys (type, evolves from, evolves to). These keys values are the desirable output. The problem is that the `type` key has a list as its value and I get this error when I try to run it:

```
Name: Bulbasaur
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pokemon.py", line 51, in <module>
    print("Type: " + info["type"])
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

The following is my code:

```
pokemon = {
    "bulbasaur": {
        "type": ["grass", "poison"],
        "evo_from": "none",
        "evo_to": "ivysaur"
        },
    "ivysaur": {
        "type": ["grass", "poison"],
        "evo_from": "bulbasaur",
        "evo_to": "venusaur"
        },
    "venusaur": {
        "type": ["grass", "poison"],
        "evo_from": "ivysaur",
        "evo_to": "none"
        },
    "charmander": {
        "type": ["fire"],
        "evo_from": "none",
        "evo_to": "charmeleon"
        },
    "charmeleon": {
        "type": ["fire"],
        "evo_from": "charmander",
        "evo_to": "charizard"
        },
    "charizard": {
        "type": ["fire", "flying"],
        "evo_from": "charmeleon",
        "evo_to": "none"
        },
    "squirtle": {
        "type": ["water"],
        "evo_from": "none",
        "evo_to": "wartortle"
        },
    "wartortle": {
        "type": ["water"],
        "evo_from": "squirtle",
        "evo_to": "blastoise"
        },
    "blastoise": {
        "type": ["water"],
        "evo_from": "wartortle",
        "evo_to": "none"
        }
    }
for poke, info in pokemon.items():
    print("\nName: " + poke.title())
    print("Type: " + info["type"])
    print("Evolves from " + info["evo_from"])
    print("Evolves to " + info["evo_to"])
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
Name: Bulbasaur
Type: Grass, Poison
Evolves from none
Evolves to Ivysaur
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `type` dict member is a list and you cannot concatenate a string and list. Instead join all the members of the list into a string and display that.

```
print("Type: " + ', '.join(info["type"]))
```

or if you wished to display the list in usual repl format

```
print("Type: %r" % info["type"])
```

Comment: Thank you, ".join" worked. And gave me the exact output i was looking for.

Comment: note that concatenating strings is generally avoided in favour of `str.format` or using the `%` operator (like my second example). If you are concatenating several strings together, there is a series of temporary objects created, which is slow. The `str.format` method avoids that. For concatenating 2 strings its not really an issue, but worth being mindful of.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, you can't concatenate strings and lists, without converting the latter to a string.

Fortunately, for `print` you don't need to concatenate. You can just print the two items separately:

```
print("Type:", info["type"])
```

This will use the default Python representation of the list. If you want to customize this, you can use `str.join`:

```
print("Type:", ", ".join(info["type"]))
```

Comment: Or the former to a list.

Answer (score 1):

type is a list and you need to treat it as such, you need to decide how you want to display the elements of the list with your string,

As a start, you may want them comma separated

```
"Type: {}".format(','.join(info["type"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have `types` as a list. you want to use `str.join()`:

```
for poke, info in pokemon.items():
    print("\nName: " + poke.title())
    print("Type: " + ', '.join(info["type"]))
    print("Evolves from " + info["evo_from"])
    print("Evolves to " + info["evo_to"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this line :

```
    print("Type: " + info["type"])
```

to this :

```
    print("Type: " + str(info["type"]))
```